# Diff tool that can compare sub-sections of files

Tags: eclipse, refactoring, eclipse-plugin, diff

I'm looking for a diff tool that will allow me to compare just a sub-section of a file with a section of another file, or even of itself. Preferably eclipse based but will take all suggestions.

Yes I know I can copy out the two sections into different files and compare those, but that is very tedious when you are trying to do a large amount of refactoring.

Basically I'm trying to remove as much duplicated code as possible from a code base that is suffering from a great deal of ctrl-V 'inheritance' ;-) However the pasted parts have evolved apart a little over time.

Comment: +1 from me - I'm always taking 3 or 4 lines of *something* (an error code, some xml, a GUID etc...) and trying to compare it with something else.  Putting them into 2 files works, but its a pain.

Comment: THanks for all the suggestions of dupe finders, I checked them out. I found a plugin that uses simian in eclipse.

The issue isn't really finding the dupes. I already know where most of the dupes actually are. Its the point where you need to figure out how to resolve the dupes that is where I'm currently at... which is why I need to diff the sections directly.

Comment: @EvilPuppetMaster: Yes, it is not the finding but the diffing that is the key. I asked as [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818082/how-to-diff-two-regions-of-the-same-file-in-eclipse). Going to investigate Atomiq.

Answer (score 4):

I've been playing with [Atomiq](http://nimblepros.com/products/atomiq.aspx), which finds duplicates within a single file. So far it looks to be a decent tool.

Comment: Atomiq has an official website now that has a lot more information: http://www.getatomiq.com

Answer (score 3):

Try using [Diffuse](http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/).  Just paste the two sub-sections you wish to compare into separate panes and press CTRL-L to re-align them.  You could also load the files and manually adjust the alignment to match up the sub-sections of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Two two tools I have used to root out duplicate code are [Simian](http://www.redhillconsulting.com.au/products/simian/) and [CopyPasteKiller](http://blog.nitriq.com/CopyPasteKillerFreeCodeSimilarityFinder.aspx). Both are useful, although IMO CopyPasteKiller is a little easier to get started with. It appears there is an [Eclipse plugin](http://www.eclipse-plugins.info/eclipse/plugin_details.jsp?id=946) for Simian, although I have not used it myself.

Answer (score 1):

**CheckStyle** is nicely integrated with Eclipse and will do the job. It will notify to you and error/warning if your code is duplicated, how much times... etc...

http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/

**Kdiff3** would be the other choice. Not Eclipse integrated, but a very nice free, cross-platform tool for merging, comparing files etc.

Answer (score 0):

See [SD CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone/index.html), a tool that detects exact and near-miss clones according to language syntax, for a large number of languages (Java, C#, PHP, C++, C, COBOL, Ada, ...).  An Eclipse API is being readied at this moment, and is likely available January 1, 2010.